# Printing statfs items in OS X returns 0

Tags: c++, macos

I'm new at programming so I'm sure this has an embarrassingly simple answer.

I'm trying to write a bit of code that pulls the system's default block size in OS X. I found statfs and think I have the right data member of the statfs struct, but here I am getting nothing but null values when I run the program.

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    struct statfs buf;
    cout << buf.f_blocks << "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called anything to populate `buf`.  You need to call either `fstatfs` or `statfs`, passing `buf` as an argument.

Both `statfs` and `fstatfs` take an additional argument.  Run `man statfs` to see the manual page.

Comment: Thanks — I was afraid of that. I have no idea how to call the function correctly. Xcode complains about all my attempts. 

***Definition:***
`statfs(const char *path, struct statfs *buf);`

***Failed call attempt:***

 struct statfs buf;
 char path = '/';
 statfs(*path, buf.statfs::f_owner);

Comment: The problem is you're not passing a string for the path, and you're not passing the address of `buf`.  The following should work:  `statfs("/", &buf);`

Comment: Hey, thanks! I got it! Is there a more efficient way of doing it than this do you think?

`int main()
{
 struct statfs buf;
 statfs("/", &buf); //system call to statfs
 uint32_t blockSize = buf.f_bsize;
 cout << blockSize << " bytes\n";
 }`

Comment: That's about as efficient as it gets.  The extra line assigning `buf.f_bsize` to `blockSize` doesn't cost anything in practice; the compiler optimizes it away.